# How to change my trigger

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I created this trigger in sqlite when I run an update, the trigger I create a new record, with months and years, 
how can I make sure that the triggers when I put years increases by 1 year? 
in practice if I put in months = January, year = 2014, the trigger should create a new record with Month = January, year = 2015  if there is no

```
String CREATE_TABLE3="CREATE TABLE "+STIPENDI+" ("+STIPENDI_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+MESI+" NUMERIC,"+ANNI+" TEXT,"+STIPENDIO+" NUMERIC)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE3);


        db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS AGGIUNGI_MESE AFTER UPDATE ON " 
                + STIPENDI + " FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new.stipendio > 0) BEGIN INSERT INTO "
                + STIPENDI + " (mesi,anni) VALUES (new.mesi,new.anni); END");
```

Comment: The description is incomprehensible. Show some example records and the desired changes.

Comment: when the trigger I create a new record, I want the value to be incremented by 1 anni for example, if the value of anni =1 , in the new record must be 2

Comment: How should I know what the problem with your data is when you still have not shown any examples?

Comment: The database in three columns: 
Salary, Months and Years, when I insert a given, the trigger I add a new record. 
For example, I insert salary in January 2014, through the trigger, create a new record. 
This new record contains the month and year, but the year that always brings me back to 2014, I wish the trigger would create a new record in January 2015, in practice should increase the value in the new record 2014 + 1.

Comment: An UPDATE trigger does not fire for INSERTs.

Comment: the trigger works, but does not count the increase, if I do an update / insert I create a new record, but if it always brings me back years in 2014 and 2014

Answer (score 0):

To insert a record with an `anni` value that is one larger, add `1`:

```
INSERT ... VALUES (NEW.mesi, NEW.anni + 1)
```

Comment: It may be that the ANNI column and numeric problem?